# Problem after installing gnome-desktop

Tags: installation, gnome, apt, openoffice.org

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and upgraded to Gnome 3.10. But when I was trying to install `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` I got error with Libreoffice. I was using Openoffice(I removed Libreoffice while installing Openoffice) I got the following error message.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.1.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I already tried `sudo apt-get -f install` it tries to install `libreoffice-common` but got the following error

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.1.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):                                                                                          
trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.0-9714                                                                                                
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/’: No such file or directory          
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/share/’: No such file or directory                 
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/program/’: No such file or directory               
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice’: No such file or directory                        
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice’: No such file or directory                        
Processing triggers for man-db ...                                                               
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog                                                   
debconf: (Dialog frontend requires a screen at least 13 lines tall and 31 columns wide.)         
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline                                                      
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme ...                                                     
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...                                                   
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...                                                     
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'                                                             
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'                                                        
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'                                                             
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for mime-support ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.1.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried manually removing `/usr/bin/soffice`, `openoffice` & `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`but still the same problem. `autoremove`, `autoclean` & `clean` doesn't seems to help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to purge `openoffice-debian-menus` by running the below command,

```
sudo dpkg --purge openoffice-debian-menus
```

Then run the below command,

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Runing `purge` asks to run `-f install` and it returns the same problem.

Comment: let us discuss here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company.

Comment: `dpkg --purge` worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. I tried

   ```
   sudo aptitude purge libreoffice*.*
   ```
2. Then reinstalled again Libreoffice via Synaptic